# accessing JS variable in HTML+JS string

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a string containing some HTML. Within that HTML there is a bit of `<script>`, within which there is a variable defined. How do I access that variable?

e.g. I make XHR request, which returns something like:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- irrelevant code -->
<head>
<body>
<!-- irrelevant code -->
<script>var bar = {car: tar};</script>
<!-- irrelevant code -->
</body>
</html>
```

And I need to access the `bar` variable. Basically what's happening, I have access to a script `dom.ltd/foo.js`, which makes XHR request to `dom.ltd/bar.php` which returns HTML+JS.

JS holds JSON string which is generated on server side. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to touch the PHP, therefore I need to parse it out of the returned string.

Comment: You can pass that variable in a hidden element as a JSON string and read it afterwards with js.

Comment: That's not an option since I don't have control over the output of the requested file.

Comment: From *where* exactly do you need to read the var? Could you post a snippet of the "reading" code?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to accomplish that is to cut the string and `eval()` anything which is written between the `<script>` tags. I don't want to raise my finger and tell you that this can be a dangerous thing (it can be if the source is not trusted), so here is the deal:

```
var recv = "<html><head><body><script>var bar = {car: 'tar'};</script></body></html>",
    code = /<script>(.*?)<\/script>/.exec(recv)[ 1 ];

eval(code); 
console.log( bar ); // Object { car="tar" }
```

I would describe the above as **horrible** code, since parsing HTML with regexp is a bad thing, `eval` is a bad thing and transfering HTML to the client is a bad thing.
However, in a very small sandbox environment this would work. If there is no way you can change the server behavior to transmit JSON-data instead of HTML, you really need to make sure that there can't be any malicous code in there.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the bar variable is always an array in that format I would go for something like this:

```
var bar = response.substring(indexOf("{"), indexOf("}"));
```